# Move the gnome-panel to second monitor (Linux Mint 11/12, Gnome 2 & 3)

Tags: linux, gnome-panel, linux-mint

## Introduction

I'm new to Linux Mint but I do use Linux since 2003 (mostly Debian and Ubuntu). Up to now it was always possible to easily move a panel in Gnome to wherever I wanted it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Button1 (left mouse)</kbd> to move the panel. In Linux Mint this does not seem to work.

## Question

How can I move a gnome-panel to my second monitor in Linux Mint?

## Information

I use

- a freshly installed Linux Mint 11 "Katya"
- Gnome 2.3 / Gnome 3
- GNOME-Panel 2.32.1
- Compiz 0.9.4.0

In earlier Versions

- I was first able to move it like any other windows just with Button1
- later I needed <kbd>Button1</kbd> to move it

Solution for others to see

## Gnome 2.3:

In the panel options uncheck "expand panel", then it is possible to simply move the panel anywhere you want.

Very intuitive... not! But it works.

## Gnome 3:.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `xrandr` to set a primary monitor.

First use the `-q` option to discover the "name" of your other monitor.  The 2nd one is probably the one with a shift, here: `+1440` after the resolution `1280x800` for `LVDS1`.

```
> xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2720 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 190mm
   1280x800       60.0*+   50.0  
[...]
VGA1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 257mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
[...]
```

Than set that monitor to primary:

```
> xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary
```

Comment: Great hint! According to http://blog.nachtarbeiter.net/2012/01/09/change-primary-monitor-in-gnome-3/comment-page-1/#comment-54044 this isn't permanent, though; but apparently in the gnome-display-settings dialog you can move that tiny black bar between the displayed monitors, which should make a permanent change. It's really difficult to discover, though :-)

Comment: you saved my day! I have been dragging them to other monitors for years!